# Conditional Formatting IconSets based on other cells values

Tags: excel, formatting

Is there a way to apply IconSets conditional formatting based on values in other cells?

Or, is there a way to add the Excel IconSets to cells formatting without conditional formatting?

Comment: Your question needs more detail - sample data and the expected output. Maybe there's a workaround but it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/awU3MTJ
As you can see in the screenshot, the first table already has applied formatting, based on other conditions. I want to copy only the circle icons from the second table to the first. Those icons are applied by Excel based on conditional formatting on the second table but I want them on the first (based on the values in the second table). 

Does that make more sense?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: That's quite unfortunate. I tried all kinds of potential workarounds and nothing works. Only thing that allows me to do it is if I place objects in the cells manually but that's just too much manual work and considering I have like 40 tables like the example, it's just not worth it.

Comment: quite sad. I've been trying to get this working but the amazing openpyxl documentation is very vague at best. There's not enough examples in there. A basic iconset based on a series of if elses is not even possible.